# creating a user in Azure AD and after the creation the user should be put in the owner group of a SharePoint Site

Tags: azure-active-directory, power-automate

I would like to create user in Azure ID. After the user is created, the user should be put into the SharePoint Owner group. I'm doing this with PowerAutomate. The user hasn't go any licenses. Just existing in the Azure AD.

After I created the user with PowerAutomate I get the error message "user not found".

Maybe you can help me.

Here is my flow so far:

Flow01

[image]
Flow02

[image]
Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Created Power Automate flow as per the user request in the Azure AD as shown below

[image]

Step 2: Since I have the access for the SharePoint, I couldn’t see any error encountered in the Flow checker.

Step 3: Before creating User ID, make sure the user can access the SharePoint path. If not, please grant permission for the user for the SharePoint folder as shown below click on the 3 dots against the folder à Click Manage Access à Click + against Direct access and Grant access to the user by entering the Azure ID

[image]

[image]

Refer doc for further configuration steps from this tchinnin’s [article](https://tchinnin.com/set-a-sharepoint-group-owner-with-power-automate/) regarding your requirement for next steps.